# BlackBerry push notification - subscription handling

Tags: php, blackberry, push-notification

I've PHP application that sends pushes to different kinds of smartphones. Recently BlackBerry push was added - for this pourpose I use commonly avaliable piece of code with appears in many of stackoverflow answers.

One thing - receiver in all of them is specified as "push_all", with I presume pushes message to all devices with active subscription. So: how to target individual device?

All I had found is that in order to receive device_id I have to setup url `example.com/subscribesdk` in my server application. But what will be sent to that URL? Is there any specification available?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The specification is contained in the push api documentation. To target an individual device you use the device PIN, which is one of the values sent to the URL. You also get the model number and device OS version.

Comment: I miss understood documentation and thought that is only way to send device PIN to the server. Apparently not. Anyway your response directed me on the right track - thanks.